# CSS interface for typescript

Tags: css, typescript, interface

is there any CSS interface in typescript?
I want to define my interface which will extend it...
Something like this:

```
export interface IComponentProperties extends ICSS {
    title: string,    
    text?: string,  
    resizable?: boolean,
    connectToParent?:  string | HTMLElement,
    replaceParentContent?: boolean,
}
```

Without any css interface, my interface should look something like:

```
export interface IComponentProperties{
    // CSS props
    width?: string,
    height?: string,
    backgroundColor?: string,
    display?: string,
    position?: string,
    left?: string,
    right?: string,
    transition?: string,
    "z-index"?: string,
    "flex-direction"?: string,

    // Component props
    title: string,    
    text?: string,  
    resizable?: boolean,
    connectToParent?:  string | HTMLElement,
    replaceParentContent?: boolean,
}
```

And I must specify there every css property, which i would eventually use...
So is there any CSS interface, which I can extend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There exists `CSSStyleDeclaration`, though note that when a property value doesn't exist, the *empty string* is given instead of `undefined`:

```js
const { style } = document.createElement('div');
console.log(style.height, typeof style.height, style.height.length);
```

so you'll need to use Partial:

```
interface MyStyle extends Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> {
    title: string;
    text?: string;
}
const s: MyStyle = {
    title: 'foo',
};
```

Also note that you'll need to use `zIndex` and `flexDirection` properties, not `z-index` and `flex-direction`.